# Understanding the output of John the Ripper

Tags: john-the-ripper

The hash I am trying to break is `279412f945939ba78ce0758d3fd83daa`, it's part of a task for learning John.
I created a file hash.txt using: `echo -n 279412f945939ba78ce0758d3fd83daa > hash.txt`.

Then, I tried running `hashid` over it and it gave me md2, md5 and md4 and many more.

So I used,
`./john --wordlist=rockyou.txt --format=raw-md4 hashfile.txt`

John returned:

```
Using default input encoding: UTF-8
Loaded 1 password hash (Raw-MD4 [MD4 256/256 AVX2 8x3])
Warning: no OpenMP support for this hash type, consider --fork=2
Press 'q' or Ctrl-C to abort, almost any other key for status
0g 0:00:00:00 DONE (2021-06-07 05:21) 0g/s 19124Kp/s 19124Kc/s 19124KC/s  
filimani..clarus
Session completed.
```

Now, when I do:
`./john --show hash.txt` or `./john --show --format=raw-md4 hash.txt`
it gives:

```
0 password hashes cracked, 1 left
```

Question: What is the meaning of that `filimani..clarus`? is it the password? why `--show` is not registering it?

Comment: And what happens when you use another hash type, like MD5? You say you tried one. Did you try the others?

Comment: @schroeder Thanks for responding! I am more interested in understanding what the output means when we get terms like `filimani..clarus` or `!!1GOOD..CLARUS` or some other variant with Clarus. I am also interested in knowing how to generally proceed when one has many options from `hashid`

Comment: You check the common hash types first.

Comment: Hint: make sure you set JTR to use MD4 (not MD5), and make sure you have 'Eternity22` in the wordlist that you provide it.

Answer (score 0):

You tried `john` with MD4, but that's not a common hash type. MD5 is much more common. My guess is that you didn't try that option for john.

`filimani..clarus` are the range of words from the wordlist that it is checking.

So, it didn't show the password because it couldn't find the hash `279412f945939ba78ce0758d3fd83daa` in the wordlist you supplied.

Comment: thanks for your time! The command `./john --show --format=raw-md5 hash.txt` shows `0 password hashes cracked, 1 left`. It was not 'change of conditions but the use of the command. I found out the problem. The hash was of type `raw-md4` and john was having trouble since the correct string was not in the rockyou.txt, the wordlist being used.

Comment: The plaintext string of that hash is in the rockyou.txt list. I still think there are factors here that you are not fully explaining.